# Installing Octave on Red Hat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, octave

I am trying to reinstall Octave on Red Hat. I currently have Octave 2.4 installed on the computer, but it is too old and some of my scripts are not running.

On the [Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?OctaveForGNULinux) it says:

> Octave is included with RedHat. If you are still using an old version
>   of RedHat and want a newer version of octave, your best options are to
>   consider updating your distribution to a recent Fedora release or
>   compile octave from source.

Updating the distribution is definitely not an option because the computer belongs to the department. I believe I need to compile Octave from source but I'm not sure what that means.

I've downloaded the tar.gz file, have decompressed the file, but I don't know how to proceed. Has anyone tried this installation before? Any ideas?

Comment: There should be a README or INSTALL file (in plain ASCII text format) that will provide some instructions on how to compile (it usually involves using these commands:  ./configure, make, make install).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've used configure command, but there seems to be an additional problem. It says that the gcc version won´t compile octave. I'm trying to install it using the package manager, but it gets stuck!

I´ve done some research and it says that maybe the databases are corrupted. Any help will be greatly appreciated.